# I want to say I "re-realized", but not "remembered" and "was reminded"

Tags: word-choice

Here is a sample text of what I wanted to write:

> I woke up very hungry this morning. Hunger is good in that it drives
>   you. But I re-realized that too much hunger is actually destructive.

It's an informal blog post, but I'm looking for an actual word that means something between "I reminded myself" and "I was reminded".

I realize that I could shuffle sentence structure around to mean a similar thing, but is there a word that I can substitute for "re-realize"?

Comment: `I'm looking for an actual word that means something between "I reminded myself" and "I was reminded".` What do you actually want to say? Realise is for when it's some new knowledge for you. Remember is when you knew it before, but had forgotten.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In that sentence I would use the phrase "Realized once again" - it implies that you've had this realization before, but it's occurring to you once more, rather than remembering a past time when it occurred to you.

Comment: "Yet" would also add some flavor

Answer (score 2):

If I were writing that, I would say "I found new reason to recall that."

Answer (score 1):

If this is meant to imply that you needed to re-process the fact, as opposed to just summon the fact again, I might draw attention to that with a stylistically jarred us of another word. For instance, `re-cognize` springs to mind, but I pride myself on bad taste.